# How to fix 'Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "is_kw", value = logical(0)) : replacement has 0 rows, data has 7' in R

Tags: r

I am trying an Text Context analyses:

```
library(corpustools)

tc <- create_tcorpus(doc, doc_colum = "id")
hits <- tc$search_features('"place places*"~5')
kwic <- tc$kwic(hits, ntokens = 3)
head(kwic$kwic,3)
```

before I reach the `tc$kwic` command the Following Error occurred:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "is_kw", value = logical(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 7
```

Has anybody an Ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The error says that your replacement data is empty. What do `str(hits)` and `str(kwic)` look like? Chances are that at least one of them indicates your problem (and I'm not a `corpustools` user, to it could be earlier in your code base).

Comment: it´s not creating an kwic dataset. I am assuming it´s a problem with the input data. Just tried it with a different data input and it worked, but with a further Data input i didn’t. i used three papers.

Comment: Since it works with another dataset and we don't have your data, this is going to be difficult to reproduce. Since the step is failing in `tc$search_features(...)`, are you able to provide a subset of your data that still fails? I say "subset" because often (1) data is too large, or (2) data is proprietary and not releasable. Please try to reduce your data and then giving us sample data with `dput(reduced_tc)`.

Comment: The concept of ‘place’, and general references to ‘geographies of …’ are making gradual incursions into nursing literature. Although the idea of place in nursing is not new, this recent spatial turn seems to be influenced by the increasing profile of the discipline of health geography, and the broadening of its scope to incorporate smaller and more intimate spatial scales.

Comment: that is a part of the paper I am working with

Comment: That might be interesting, but what relevance does it have on the question? Is that the content of `doc$id`? It's unclear to me how that text will be used in your code. Can you be explicit? Please edit your question and include the relevant subset of your data using the output from `dput`.